# 2 Magento installs (version 1.9.2.4) on same server, is it good idea?

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

We have 2 stores Magento installs (version 1.9.2.4) each with 24,000 customers and 4,000 products on each with over 15 extensions installed on each and approx 20,000 orders on one of them and 10 orders on the other one. My question is it ok to use one server for both sites or would it be best to have seperate server for each?

We plan on getting a 128GB DDR4 ECC 2133MHZ Intel Xeon E5-1650v3 3.5GHz/3.8GHz with 4 x 800GB SSD + Hard Raid + FastPath

Answer (score 0):

I  always suggest for septate server,

Because in pick time your server handle request from both website, and it may possible because of that much request your server response  gets slow and you have to suffer from performance issue. Because there is 70-80 Avg request per page so they frustrated because of slow page load and all.

and your page load time increase and may possible customer frustrated .

But its completely depend on traffic on your server.

But In my opinion different server is the best solution.